# MongoDB Find based on Document Key

Tags: mongodb

I have documents in a collection with two counter fields. Want to find documents where counter1 count is greater than counter2 count. How do I pass counter2 key as a variable in the find query? I want something like this ...

```
db.collection.find( { counter1: { $gt: counter2 }})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the mongoDB Aggregation framework (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/)or map-reduce (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/ )which will give you the capability to achieve it.